# CMFCRibbonBar: GetEditText() doesn't return the actual edit box text of a CMFCRibbonComboBox unless window loses the focus

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack, cmfcribbonpanel

I have a VS2008 project with a 'Find' panel containing an editable combo box as well as a forward and a backward search button. When I press a search button, `GetEditText()` returns an outdated value.

```
CMainFrame *pFrame = static_cast<CMainFrame*>(GetTopLevelFrame());
CMFCRibbonBar* pRibbon = pFrame->GetRibbonBar();
ASSERT_VALID(pRibbon);
CMFCRibbonComboBox* pFindCombobox = 
    DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonComboBox, pRibbon->FindByID(ID_MY_FIND_COMBOBOX));

// this returns the last value before the combo box edit field got the focus:
pFindCombobox->GetEditText();
```

Is there a standard way to 'flush' the edit field's content to the value buffer accessed by `GetEditText()`?

I noticed that in VS2010 there is a `SetFocused()` member in the `CMFCRibbonPanel` class, which could be used to steal the focus from the combobox and presumably force `GetEditText()` to return the right value, but it is missing in VS2008.

I'm currently running out of ideas how to handle this. Hope anyone has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have helped myself with a `SetFocus()` to the MDI child window before I call `GetEditText()`. But it's not the nicest workaround for sure!